# Suppress pages in Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, input

My project uses multiple inputs to tex files that contain frames for a specific topic.

Example:

- main.tex
- topics

  - topic1.tex
  - topic2.tex
  - topic3.tex

This is in the main.tex:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
  \input{topics/topic1}
  \input{topics/topic2}
  \input{topics/topic3}
\end{document}
```

Depending on how far I come during the presentation, I want to suppress the first n frames in the next presentation (for example the first 20 of topic1) and the last m frames (for example the last 10 of topic3).

I want to do this, without having to change the topics (no commenting out slides or so), but by using a command for this.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the `\lecture` command of beamer. You could place them at the desired break points and then compile only the upcomming lecture

Comment: or compile the complete presentation and then filter out the desired pages with an external tool, e.g. `pdftk presentation.pdf cat 20-40 output out.pdf` will create a new file with only  the pages 20-40

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to use beamers `\lecture` command and place it at each break point. This way you can compile only the frames for the next lecture.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\includeonlylecture{weekb}

\begin{document}

\lecture{week a}{weeka}

\begin{frame}
topic 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
more from topic 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
topic 2
\end{frame}

\lecture{week b}{weekb}

\begin{frame}
more from topic 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
topic 3
\end{frame}

\lecture{week c}{weekc}

\begin{frame}
more from topic 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

Another possibility could be to compile the complete presentation and then filter out the slides you need with some external program, e.g.

```
 pdftk presentation.pdf cat 20-40 output out.pdf
```